# on('click', function() doesn't work on new content

Tags: jquery, ajax

**HTML**

```
<div id='story'>    
    <div class='item folder'>sky</div>
    <div class='item folder'>sea</div> 
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(".item").on('click', function(){
    $('.marked').removeClass('marked');
    $(this).addClass('marked');
});
```

This works but now the the content of `#story` is replaced using ajax procedure:

```
...    
success: function(data) {
    $('#story').html(data);
}
```

And the new content is:

```
<div class='item folder'>earth</div>
<div class='item folder'>venus</div>
```

And here `on('click', function()` doesn't work. Classes are not removed/added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) does the trick:

```
$('body').on('click', '.item', function(){
    $('.marked').removeClass('marked');
    $(this).addClass('marked');
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Solved.

Answer (score 2):

Use **event delegation** for dinamically added elements:

```
$(document).on('click', '.item', function(){
    $('.marked').removeClass('marked');
    $(this).addClass('marked');
});
```

You can read more **[here](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)**.

Answer (score 0):

Click binding only work for html elements, which are available in the DOM at the time `click` is called. You have to bind a new click listener after you add something to the DOM.